# Electrical plug at bathroom sink, can it be located in a cabinet next to bathroom sink?

Tags: electrical

To fulfill code requirements - can an electrical plug at bathroom sink be located in a cabinet next to sink

Comment: You're talking about a separate cabinet right? Not the one containing the plumbing and sink on top.  Should be fine as long as it's GFCI

Answer (score 5):

No, the receptacle within an adjacent cabinet does not satisfy the code requirement.

> **210.52(D) - Bathrooms.**
>
> In dwelling units, at least one receptacle outlet shall be installed
>   in bathrooms within (3 ft) of the outside edge of each basin. The
>   receptacle outlet shall be located on a wall or partition that is
>   adjacent to the basin or basin countertop, located on the countertop,
>   or installed on the side or face of the basin cabinet. In no case
>   shall the receptacle be located more than (12 in.) below the top of
>   the basin.

---

> **210.52 - Dwelling Unit Receptacle Outlets**
>
> The receptacles required by this section shall be in addition to any
>   receptacle that is:
>
> (3) Located within cabinets or cupboards